# css for media queries and height issue

Tags: css, media-queries

I have an image background for a div that I want to show on different devices, The problem is that I have to give height of the image in order to fit it correctly. Now on different phones, I have to adjust the height with different px. forexample on iphones 65px works for portrait mode but not for landscape and etc. Is there a way that the div just gets resized in height to cover 100% of the background image?
here is my code

```
<style>
    div.testing {
        height: 95px;
        background-image: url(/myimageurl);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
        /* iphone portrait */
        div.testing {
            height: 65px;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
        /* iphone portrait */
        div.testing {
            height: 80px;
        }
    }
   </style>

    <div class="testing">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: and if I use background-size:cover then the width becomes an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use background-size: cover;

```
.thing {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

but why are you using a background-image? if you can use a regular image, you could do it like this:

```
.thing {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: [your biggest width];
}

.thing img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

ALSO

I would recommend flipping your mindset on the max-width and start small screen first, using min-width and getting bigger.

And you don't really need div.testing - it can just be .testing

And if you are using a background image for a good reason... you should investigate making the div -

```
.thing { 
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30%; /* play with this */
}
```

This will keep the proportions... but it's only useful in specific cases.

A complete jsfiddle with an actual image would be useful.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Nest your div inside the background div and set the height to 100%